# How to upload csv file using dropbox python API?

Tags: python, csv, heroku, dropbox-api

I've built an app in flask that captures data and stores it in an SQl database. I want the app to pull down the data collected and upload it as a csv file to dropbox at the click of a button. I should also mention that the app is currently deployed on a Heroku server so I'm working with their ephemeral filesystem. Here's my code:

```
    #select the target day out of holder  
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
targetDate = calculateAdmin()

cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM allReservations WHERE date = %s''', [targetDate])
data = cur.fetchall()
keys = data[0].keys()

#get date for output file name
cur.execute('''SELECT * FROM adminHolder''')
bollucks = cur.fetchall()
title = bollucks[0]["day"]

#write data to csv file
a_file = open("output.csv", "w")
dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(a_file, keys)
dict_writer.writeheader()
dict_writer.writerows(data)
a_file.close()

#upload file to dropbox
file_location = f"/Beeg-Yoishi/{a_file}"
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("<ACCESS_TOKEN>")

with open("output.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    dbx.files_upload(reader, file_location)

return render_template("download.html")
```

Right now I can write the data to the csv file and pull the file down from the Heroku server just fine. But when I try to upload the file to dropbox the file is titled <_io.TextIOWrapper name='output.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> instead of "output.csv" and I get an error saying I can't view the file. Any suggestions?

Comment: `a_file` is a Python object representing the file. But your code is treating it as if it were a filename:  `file_location = f"/Beeg-Yoishi/{a_file}"`. Shouldn't that be `file_location = f"/Beeg-Yoishi/output.csv"`?

Comment: @Bisforbilliam I redacted your access token, but you should revoke it since it was posted publicly.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two issues here:

1.

> when I try to upload the file to dropbox the file is titled <_io.TextIOWrapper name='output.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'> instead of "output.csv"

As BoarGules correctly pointed out:

> `a_file` is a Python object representing the file. But your code is treating it as if it were a filename: `file_location = f"/Beeg-Yoishi/{a_file}"`. Shouldn't that be `file_location = f"/Beeg-Yoishi/output.csv"`

Indeed, the uploaded Dropbox file name is set via the second parameter to [`files_upload`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_upload), which was set to the `file_location` variable.

2.

> I get an error saying I can't view the file.

The actual data that gets uploaded is set via the first parameter to [`files_upload`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox_client.Dropbox.files_upload), which was set to `reader` here. That's a csv reader object, not the actual data. That should be something like `f.read()` instead.